# Filling value in field of attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I need to put a value of 1 in a field of my shapefile's attribute table.

How to do it using ArcPy?

I have already added a new field using   `arcpy.AddField_management` and now I want to fill 1 in the newly added field.

Comment: You might want to check these out: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303660/calculating-field-with-arcpy-cursor 
As well as this:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/updatecursor.htm

Comment: You have worked out how to call the add field tool, why not call the calculate field tool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the da.UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\folder\shapefile.shp'
field_to_update = 'somefieldname'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field_to_update) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = 1
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```